# How to upgrade dnf to el8 from el7 after upgrading Centos from 7 to 8 stream

Tags: linux, centos, dnf

I have upgraded Centos 7 to Centos 8 accordingly this instruction
https://techviewleo.com/how-to-convert-from-centos-to-centos-stream/.

Now I have some problems with installing some packeges.I would like to upgrade dnf version to el8. Current version is dnf-0:4.0.9.2-2.el7_9.noarch.

Yum has been deleted.
dnf update dnf --best --allowerasing
Result:
rpmlib(RichDependencies) <= 4.12.0-1 is needed for some packeges.
rpm --rebuilddb  - doesn't help
How can I upgrade dnf to el8?

Comment: dnf install http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8-stream/BaseOS/aarch64/os/Packages/dnf-4.4.2-11.el8.noarch.rpm --allowerasing                                                                                                     Result: Error: transaction check vs depsolve:
(gcc >= 8 with gcc < 9) is needed by annobin-10.94-1.el8.x86_64
rpmlib(RichDependencies) <= 4.12.0-1 is needed by annobin-10.94-1.el8.x86_64
(annobin if gcc) is needed by redhat-rpm-config-130-1.el8.noarch                                     
 gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-17)

Comment: This seems more apporpriate to https://unix.stackexchange.com . Please delete here and repost there. Also learn to use the `Edit` menu options for formatting. Highlight text that should look like code, data, errMsgs (with your mouse) and then click on the `{}` tool in the `Edit` menu. It may look differnt on the `Unix` S.E, but that feature it there. Also, please don't expect readers to try an dechiper detailed information in comments. That should be added to the body of your main questrion. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this issue by execute the following command.

```
dnf upgrade rpm --releasever=8 --setopt=deltarpm=false --best --allowerasing
```

If there are some python2 conflicted packages, you need to upgrade them manually.

```
dnf remove python-zope-event-4.0.3-2.el7.noarch -y
dnf install -y python2-zope-component
```

This is not OK for `openssl-libs`, for rpm or dnf requires the old `openssl11-libs` to run.

```
dnf download openssl-libs
rpm2cpio openssl-libs-*.el8.x86_64.rpm | cpio -idmvD tmpdir
rpm -e --nodeps openssl11-libs
mv tmpdir/usr/lib64/* /usr/lib64/
dnf install -y openssl-libs
```